# As a Magus, does Spellstrike take 3 actions?

Tags: movement, actions, pathfinder-2e, action-economy

I'm level 2 right now. My DM says it takes 1 action to melee with Spellstrike, and 2 actions to cast my spell. Which means that's all 3 of my actions... So I can't move to an enemy to use my skill?

I'm pretty new, but this just doesn't feel right. I have to start my turn next to an enemy, or I can never use my skill.

Comment: It is possible that your GM has in mind the playtest rules for Magus, in which Spellstrike was a 3 action activity.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Ask your DM how [Eldritch Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=59&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) works

Comment: Spellstrike is not a skill, but a class feature.

Answer (score 25):

## Answer

The Spellstrike activity allows you to Cast a Spell and Strike spending only the two actions required by Spellstrike.

## Sources

The Core Rulebook states the following on page 461 under [Actions -> Activities](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=388):

> An  activity  might  cause  you  to  use  specific  actions  within it. You don’t have to spend additional actions to perform them—they’re already factored into the activity’s required actions. (See Subordinate Actions on page 462.)

A subordinate action is described like this in the [Core rulebook page 462](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=387):

> An action might allow you to use a simpler action—usually one  of  the  Basic  Actions  on  page  469—in  a  different  circumstance  or  with  different  effects. This  subordinate  action still has its normal traits and effects, but is modified in  any  ways  listed  in  the  larger  action.
>
> [...]
>
> The action that allows you to use a subordinate action doesn’t require you to spend more actions or reactions to do so; that cost is already factored in.

The [Spellstrike activity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755) states the following (Secrets of Magic page 37):

> You  Cast  a  Spell  that  takes  1  or  2  actions  to  cast  and  requires  a  spell  attack  roll.  The effects of the spell don’t occur immediately but are imbued  into  your  attack  instead.  Make  a  melee  Strike  with  a  weapon  or  unarmed  attack.

So Cast a Spell and Strike are subordinate actions to Spellstrike and thus do not require you to spend more actions to perform them, their action cost is already included in the action cost of Spellstrike. (See the [Magus Class Description](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=17) for more info)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to look for a forum on this, but couldn't find any. This really cleared it up! This is the writer btw, just wanted to say thanks, again I guess. You're the best

Comment: @Calarious if this answer resolved the problem, consider upvoting and accepting it :)

Answer (score 9):

You are correct in that Spellstrike only consumes 2 actions, and Dylfaen gave an excellent breakdown of why that is (that the Strike is a subordinate action). I would add that you can also point to your DM how the "three actions" of Spellstrike work.

**Spellstrike (2 actions)**

> You Cast a Spell that takes 1 or 2 actions to cast and requires a spell attack roll. The effects of the spell don't occur immediately but are imbued into your attack instead. Make a melee Strike with a weapon or unarmed attack... After you use Spellstrike, you can't do so again until you recharge your Spellstrike as a single action, which has the concentrate trait. You also recharge your Spellstrike when you cast a conflux spell that takes at least 1 action to cast; casting a focus spell of another type doesn't recharge your Spellstrike.

Essentially, it is two actions to do everything for Spellstrike itself. But it takes one or more actions to then make Spellstrike usable again. This may be the source of confusion for your DM, and so would be a useful passage to point out to them.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying "one or more actions, on that or a future turn, to then make Spellstrike available again."